# Tiff Conversion Inverted

Tags: c#, tiff

i am converting 8bpp tif file to 8bpp grayscale but it goes larger in file size. i referred 
the following url [wischik](http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/1bpp.html) i have tried atalasoft the file size is fine but the some of the files goes negative in irfanview.

can you guys tell me to solve the above both problem(filesize, negative)?

Answer (score 0):

Images size depends on many factors like bpp, compression, colors..etc
Since you have two tiff 8bpp images I believe the most important factor is the compression since both images will contain palettes.
Ideally in your case the two images should be close in size (memory required) when using the same compression but the colored image will most likely be smaller. I have a sdk called leadtools that I use in my development and it gave me the result above.

Also a small note, maybe if you can provide a sample on the image you are facing the problem with we can help you more.